# 'cabal copy' failed during `stack build` in cifs directory

Tags: haskell, nfs, haskell-stack, cifs

I'm following [these instructions](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#downloading-and-installation). I successfully did `stack new` and `stack setup` but `stack build` fails.

I found a [git issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2500) that this may be due to extra files listed in the cabal file, but removing them didn't fix the issue (and I'm just using the `new-template` without any changes). I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and installed stack using the script. Is there anything else I can look into?

It appears that this might be due to me trying to build inside of a cifs directory. Is there anything I can do to handle this?

```
# stack build
ehri-haskell-0.1.0.0: configure (lib + exe)
Configuring ehri-haskell-0.1.0.0...
ehri-haskell-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library ehri-haskell-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'ehri-haskell-exe' for ehri-haskell-0.1.0.0...
ehri-haskell-0.1.0.0: copy/register
Installing library in
/mnt/docs/RubymineProjects/ehri-haskell/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-8.6/8.0.2/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.2/ehri-haskell-0.1.0.0-Kh3VLZPfbij7EgcL22QBMN
Installing executable(s) in
/mnt/docs/RubymineProjects/ehri-haskell/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-8.6/8.0.2/bin
/mnt/docs/RubymineProjects/ehri-haskell/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-8.6/8.0.2/bin/.copyFile5965166491189641421.tmp:
copyFile: does not exist (Host is down)
'cabal copy' failed.  Error message:

--  While building package ehri-haskell-0.1.0.0 using:
      /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0 copy
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1

One possible cause of this issue is:
* No module named "Main". The 'main-is' source file should usually have a header indicating that it's a 'Main' module.

# stack --version
Version 1.4.0, Git revision e714f1dd3fade19496d91bd6a017e435a96a6bcd (4640 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.0
```

Comment: Have you solved it? It bugs me

Comment: @soulomoon nope

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is caused by the depth of the folder where the project lives (Windows 10, x64). From the moment the depth exceeds some threshold, described error appears. So try moving the project folder up in directories tree.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I symbolically linked it to `/root/aci` and still get the same error when building from there (Ubuntu)

Comment: in my case, package.yml was referring to the LICENSE file, which did not exist in my project